# 3D subplots spacing in PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to increase the size of the 3d subplots to occupy most of the empty white space. I am using Gridspec (maybe I'm not using it properly?). I have posted the minimal working example and the output image. You can see the plot is big, but the 3D subplots are smaller with a lot of space between them. How do I increase the size of each subplot to occupy all that empty space?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 17))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(6, 4)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2, 0:2], projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2,2:], projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4,0:2], projection='3d')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4,2:], projection='3d')
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:6,1:3], projection='3d')

axs = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5]


for ax in axs:
    ax.set_xlabel('$\psi_2$', fontname='sans serif', fontsize=20)
    ax.set_ylabel('$\psi_3$', fontname='sans serif', fontsize=20)
    ax.set_zlabel('$\psi_4$', fontname='sans serif', fontsize=20)
    ax.view_init(elev=28., azim=81)
    
plt.tight_layout()
gs.tight_layout(fig)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can deactivate the tight layout and set each interval to a minimum of 0 horizontally and vertically. Negative values will cause each graph to overlap.

```
# plt.tight_layout()
# gs.tight_layout(fig)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```